# I am getting Error in getPackageManager method using asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-package-managers

Getting an error here

```
 try {
           PackageManager pm = MyApplication.getInstance().getPackageManager();
           PackageInfo packageInfo = process.getPackageInfo(MyApplication.getInstance(), 0);
           info.name = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
     } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
 }
```

error in Log is :

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.app.Application.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.bugfreeram.bugfreeanti.external.ProcessScanTask.doInBackground(ProcessScanTask.java:52)
    at com.example.bugfreeram.bugfreeanti.external.ProcessScanTask.doInBackground(ProcessScanTask.java:21)
```

MyApplcication class is like this :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    public static Application getInstance() {
       return sInstance;
    }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       sInstance = this;
   }
}
```

I have tried all answers as I got on StackOverflow please help me.
thank you in advance

Comment: Apparently, your `MyApplication.getInstance()` returns null.

Comment: I have added MyApplication class also

Comment: Have you declared your `MyApplication` in your manifest?

Comment: It is null because your activity or service that initiate the async task may have explicitly declared a separate process in your manifest.

Comment: ok I got it but I have one more class there and this is second to add

Comment: <application
        android:name=".AppData"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".external.MainActivityUi">

Comment: I need to add another class in manifest

Comment: Oh maybe this is the problem.. in your manifest, change `<application android:name=".AppData"` to `<application android:name=". MyApplication"`

Comment: ok I did but getting in another asynctask class error

Comment: No worries, at least we're going somewhere, could you share the log?

Answer (score 0):

Use Context object to get PackageManager. 
like this:

`PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add `MyApplication` Class to `android:name`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.packagename">
.
.

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    .
    .

</application>
```